# how to change browser preference in parasoft?

Tags: user-interface, testing, web-applications, parasoft

I am new to parasoft and trying to test some web UI functionality. I have used chrome to record the web session and it is working fine when run with chrome. But now I want to test the same on Firefox, but I am not getting any option to make it run on firefox. It always opens in chrome only.
So please, if anyone is aware of changing the browser preference to playback would be appreciated. 
as the test case is bit big, I don't want to re-record using Firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To change browser which you want to use during test, you should go to Test Configuration and select appropriate test configuration used to execute test.
Then in Execution view select browser which you want to use.Other option is to use built test configuration with selected browser already.